# pgfplots: axis tick overlayed by graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

As you can see, the "20" number is overlayed by the pink line: how can avoid this?

This is my MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
  every mark/.append style={mark size=0.5pt},
  grid, grid style={dashed, draw=gray!10},
  legend image with text/.style={
        legend image code/.code={%
            \node[anchor=center] at (0.3cm,0cm) {#1};
        }
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend cell align={left},
  grid, grid style=dashed,
  ymin=-6,ymax=6,
  xmax=55,xmin=0,  
  ytick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
  xtick={5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50},  
  extra y ticks={0},
            width=14cm,
            height=7.5cm,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,
  x label style={at={(1,0.5)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$}, 
  style={thick}
               ]                
        \addplot+[only marks, mark=*,blue] table[x=A,y=C,col sep=comma] {potAF-BF.csv};
        \draw[pink,thick] (0,0.00059252) -- (16,-0.008131576);
        \draw[pink,thick] (17,-0.008676832) -- (18,-4.45194);
        \draw[pink,thick] (18,-4.45194) -- (19,-2.21057);
        \draw[pink,thick] (19,-2.21057) -- (20,0);
        \draw[pink,thick] (20,0) -- (22,4.51354);
        \draw[pink,thick] (22,4.51354) -- (23,0.00827042);
        \draw[pink,thick] (24,0.00784436) -- (50,-0.0032332);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Link to the .csv file: https://www.transfernow.net/HgcaSv082020

Comment: Why are you plotting the data file with marks only, and then draw the lines manually after?

Comment: Your file cannot be downloaded without being registered. Put it somewhere else!

Comment: @AndréC try now!

Comment: @hpekristiansen whoops I didn't think it was enough delete the option `only marks`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `extra x ticks` with a dedicated style `extra x tick style` that shifts it to the right.

```
 extra x ticks={20}, 
 extra x tick style={xshift=6pt},
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
  every mark/.append style={mark size=0.5pt},
  grid, grid style={dashed, draw=gray!10},
  legend image with text/.style={
        legend image code/.code={%
            \node[anchor=center] at (0.3cm,0cm) {#1};
        }
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend cell align={left},
  grid, grid style=dashed,
  ymin=-6,ymax=6,
  xmax=55,xmin=0,  
  ytick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
  xtick={5,10,15,25,30,35,40,45,50}, 
  extra x ticks={20}, 
  extra x tick style={xshift=6pt},
  extra y ticks={0},
            width=14cm,
            height=7.5cm,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,
  x label style={at={(1,0.5)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$}, 
  style={thick}
               ]                
        \addplot+[only marks, mark=*,blue] table[x=A,y=C,col sep=comma] {potAF-BF.csv};
        \draw[pink,thick] (0,0.00059252) -- (16,-0.008131576);
        \draw[pink,thick] (17,-0.008676832) -- (18,-4.45194);
        \draw[pink,thick] (18,-4.45194) -- (19,-2.21057);
        \draw[pink,thick] (19,-2.21057) -- (20,0);
        \draw[pink,thick] (20,0) -- (22,4.51354);
        \draw[pink,thick] (22,4.51354) -- (23,0.00827042);
        \draw[pink,thick] (24,0.00784436) -- (50,-0.0032332);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How can I hide that vertical line above the number "20"?

Comment: Try this `extra x tick style= {shift={(6pt,-2pt)}, tickwidth=0cm, grid=none},`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `axis on top=true` option like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{
  every mark/.append style={mark size=0.5pt},
  grid, grid style={dashed, draw=gray!10},
  legend image with text/.style={
        legend image code/.code={%
            \node[anchor=center] at (0.3cm,0cm) {#1};
        }
    },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  axis on top=true,
  legend pos=outer north east,
  legend cell align={left},
  grid, grid style=dashed,
  ymin=-6,ymax=6,
  xmax=55,xmin=0,  
  ytick={-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
  xtick={5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50},  
  extra y ticks={0},
            width=14cm,
            height=7.5cm,
  axis lines = middle,
  set layers,
  x label style={at={(1,0.5)},right},
  y label style={at={(0,1)},above},
  xlabel={$x$},ylabel={$y$}, 
  style={thick}
               ]                
%        \addplot+[only marks, mark=*,blue] table[x=A,y=C,col sep=comma] {potAF-BF.csv};
        \draw[pink,thick] (0,0.00059252) -- (16,-0.008131576);
        \draw[pink,thick] (17,-0.008676832) -- (18,-4.45194);
        \draw[pink,thick] (18,-4.45194) -- (19,-2.21057);
        \draw[pink,thick] (19,-2.21057) -- (20,0);
        \draw[pink,thick] (20,0) -- (22,4.51354);
        \draw[pink,thick] (22,4.51354) -- (23,0.00827042);
        \draw[pink,thick] (24,0.00784436) -- (50,-0.0032332);                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Axis on top]